# Javascript update a value in an array within an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, real-time, updates

I'm using the Flot Chart plugin to construct a bar chart. When the script receives new data, I need it to increase that value by one.

```
var data = [["A", 0], ["B", 0], ["C", 0], ["D", 0], ["E", 0]]
$.plot("#placeholder", [data], options);
channel.on("data", function (receiveddata) {
    data[receiveddata] = data[receiveddata] + 1
    $.plot("#placeholder", [data], options);
});
```

Now say the the channel receives "A" as the data, I want  to increase by one and so on.
My code shows what i've tried and also

```
data.recieveddata
```

but nothing is working.

Comment: Why in the world are you not using an object? You are treating it like an object, so use an object. If something else requires an array, convert the object to an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, because you need to find the correct sub-array based on a letter, you can loop the outer array and when you find a match increment the data. Here is a helper function that should work:

```
function incrementArray(array, letter){
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        var subArray = array[i];
        if(subArray[0] == letter){
            subArray[1]++;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it like so:

```
channel.on("data", function (receiveddata) {
    incrementArray(data, receiveddata);
    $.plot("#placeholder", [data], options);
});
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/musefan/TCUwK/)

Answer (score 3):

You'd do that with :

```
data[0][1]++;
```

the array would now be :

```
[ ["A", 1], ["B", 0], ["C", 0], ["D", 0], ["E", 0] ]
//^     ^
//|     | 1 in second array
//0 in first array
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jHXXU/3/)

To use `A` as a key, you need an object:

```
var data = {A:0, B:0, C:0};

data[receiveddata] = 2;
```

Comment: and how do you convert `"A"` into `0`?

Comment: How can I do it so that I can update other elements like C or E?

Comment: You could use a switch statement

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

case "A":
  data[0][1]++;
  break;
case "B":
  data[1][1]++;
  break;

Comment: @JoshLukeBlease - an array only has a numbered index, if you need to use key / value pairs, you should be using an object.

Comment: @JoshLukeBlease you could use `receiveddata.charCodeAt(0)-65` to convert the string to the desired number for the array. http://jsfiddle.net/rGUKr/

Comment: @BlakePlumb: A very interesting solution - I like your thinking! (Of course, it requires that the letters are always sequential, and are not just for the purposes of this example)

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is you are referring to it as if it is a property on an object, when the data structure is an array of arrays, an array of pairs.

You could use jQuery.grep.

```
var data = [["A", 0], ["B", 0], ["C", 0], ["D", 0], ["E", 0]];

$.plot("#placeholder", [data], options);

channel.on("data", function (receiveddata) {

    var pair = $.grep(data, function (item) {
        return item[0] === receiveddata;
    })[0];

    if (pair) {
        pair[1]++;        
        $.plot("#placeholder", [data], options);
    } else {
        console.log("Could not determine receiveddata");
    }

}
```

Comment: This is making the script not work, it doesn't even begin to plot the graph?